# How to mark an Oozie workflow action's status as OK

Tags: hadoop, workflow, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I am using Apache oozie. I want to mark the status of one of the shell action as OK, in my oozie workflow. It is in Running state.

Can we please share the command to use in Apache Oozie to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly set the status of an Action. Oozie automatically does that for you based on the action/task execution. For instance, let's say you have shell action that looks something like this:

```xml
<workflow-app
    xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.3" name="shell-wf">
    <start to="shell-node"/>
    <action name="shell-node">
        <shell
            xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <exec>some-script.sh</exec>
            <file>/user/src/some-script.sh</file>
        </shell>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Shell action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

If the `/user/src/some-script.sh` execution is successful, Oozie will mark the action status as `ok` and successfully ends the job. On the other hand if the script execution encounters any error, it will be marked as `error` immediately kill the job and directed. If you're looking for not to kill the job due to any abnormal execution of the code in your script, you can create another action and direct Oozie to follow that execution path instead of immediately killing the workflow. Checkout more about [Oozie Shell Action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.0.0/DG_ShellActionExtension.html#Shell_Action).

Comment: I know that oozie does this. My question is if we want to manually set the status to OK, how do we do that? This is possible in Airflow. As my original question goes, I want to know how we can achieve this in Oozie?